# How can I limit the word count for get_the_content() on wordpress?

Tags: php, wordpress

I'm trying to limit the string output of get_the_content but I can't find anywhere on the net on how to do this.

Everything I find is regarding the_content().

I'm not using the_content because I want the string to be unformatted and because for some reason it doesn't seem to work right on my loop for all the posts I have.

Anyways, does anyone no how to make get_the_content return only a specified number of characters of the actual description? I don't want to resort to using the excerpt as that is reserved for some other information I'm using.

Comment: What solution did you find for `the_content`? Adapting it to `get_the_content` should be straightforward.

Comment: One would think, but no, for some reason they seem to work in a different manner. What I can't understand is why is there so little about this in wordpress codex. I would not have posted a question here if it were easy as that.

Comment: I'm just asking how you modified `the_content`'s output. I know that get_the_content doesn't apply filters on `the_content` before returning, so most of the WP's filters like auto paragraphs, auto smart quotes are not added.

Comment: See, that's the thing, I honestly don't know how one relates to the other. Plus there is some strangeness on how they both work. get_content() is easy as I've worked with it before but get_the_content() doesn't even take the attributes I give it in reference to what the codex says about it. I guess I'm still trying to figure out how to use it.

Comment: Sorry, I didn't answer the question. I didn't modify the_content. I'm using a theme that uses get_the_content. I tried using the_content instead but it just screws up my whole layout.

Comment: You said `I'm trying to limit the string output of get_the_content but I can't find anywhere on the net on how to do this. Everything I find is regarding the_content().`. I'm just saying that a solution for the_content could be adapted to work on get_the_content :)

Answer (score 2):

I haven't tested this but I think it will work..

Go to wp-includes/post-template.php

Find the get_the_content() function

At the end of the function, there is

```
return $output;
```

Before that final line, add

```
$output = preg_replace("/((\S+\s+){1,13}).*/s","\\1",strip_tags($output));
```

So you're left with

```
    $output = preg_replace("/((\S+\s+){1,13}).*/s","\\1",strip_tags($output));

return $output;
```

The part you'll want to change is the number "13" in the code above - just put the number of words you want to display

Let me know how that works for you

Answer (score 1):

try this. It worked of me

```
<?php $mycontent = get_the_content();
  $trimmed_content = wp_trim_words( $mycontent , 50, '<a href="'. get_permalink() .'">...[ read more ]</a>' ); ?>
  <p><?php echo $trimmed_content; ?></p>
```

(Change the 50 to your desire words length)

Answer (score 0):

try substr(),

```
$description = substr(get_the_content(), 0, $number_of_characters);
```

Comment: yes, but, if description has 2000 characters and you need only 200, you will transfer 10x more data from database then you actually need.